# Secure way of providing MySQL password in a batch file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a batch file that, among other things, performs some database operations.  To keep things non-interactive, currently we pass the DB user id and password information on the command line.  We keep getting the following warning messages:
`Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Kindly suggest how to pass the DB password information to the batch file so that it remains non-interactive and yet secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the password into an option file, and specify the option filename to your MySQL client in the batch file.

Say you edit an option file and call it "myoptions.ini". The option file content might look like this:

```
[client]
user = sandeep
password = ********
```

Then your command would look like this:

```
mysql --defaults-file myoptions.ini -h <host> <database> -e <query>
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: `mysql --defaults-extra-file my-extra-options.ini -h <host> <database> -e <query>`  appears to be a better option.

Comment: Sure, that's a good idea. It preserves whatever options are set in your global config file.